# adamIds have no return values

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

So I'm trying to scrape chart data from iTunes. I know that you can build the rss feeds from their link builder to the top charts on iTunes. However, I'm not looking to scrape the itunes store, but rather the Apple Music app located at http://itunes.apple.com.

So basically I want to scrape the data available in iTunes if you go to "Browse -> Top Charts -> See All" and scrape the data in Overall and some other genre's.

I've done my best to use the json information I've been able to collect and I'm able to scrape the first 50 songs of any chart without issue.

However, for some reason, `#51-200` have adamIds in the response I get via requests (just like the first 50) yet they all error out with a KeyError that their id doesn't point to anything and has no return value.

My code is below and I'm sure its something super dumb and simple but I've been pounding away at it long enough that I'm starting to destroy parts of the script that work just to try and make this piece function.

```
url = "http://itunes.apple.com"

chart_id = "1"

params = urllib.urlencode(
    {
        'cc': 'us',
        'popId': '81',
        'genreId': '34'
    }
)

time = datetime.datetime.now

headers = {
    "X-Apple-Store-Front": "143441-1,32 t:music3",
    "X-Apple-I-MD-M": "+EjdHJ+LfPCZZErf9bur/G4AP/SnZrwxjYlPctTGf63EFu9ThmDGqhr2lGmEAXwoKOokD6MaATf0NJp3",
"X-Apple-I-MD-RINFO": "17106176",
"X-Apple-I-Client-Time": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
"X-Apple-Tz": "7200",
"Referer": "https://apps.itunes.apple.com/files/desktop-music-app-seed/",
"X-Apple-I-MD": "AAAABQAAABDQOonnfAdO+H7jnDjjQNOhAAAAAQ==",
"Origin": "https://apps.itunes.apple.com"
};

http_conn = requests.Session()
request = http_conn.get( 
url+"/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?"+params,  headers=headers)


response = request.text.encode('utf-8')

category = "All"

data = json.loads(response)


tracks = data['storePlatformData']['lockup']['results']
trackIds = data['pageData']['selectedChart']['adamIds']

print(data)

rows = [];
i=1;
for track in trackIds:
    if len(track) == 10:
        try:
            print "Track: "+track
            sql = "INSERT INTO %s (Artist,Song,Rank,Album,chart_name,Playlist,chart_name_2,chart_type,Date) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" % (
                "songs_chart",
                escape_string(tracks[track]['artistName'].encode('utf-8')).strip(), #Artist
                escape_string(tracks[track]['name'].encode('utf-8')).strip(), #song
                escape_string(str(i).encode('utf-8')).strip(), #rank
                escape_string(tracks[track]['collectionName'].encode('utf-8')).strip(), #album
                escape_string(category.encode('utf-8')).strip(), #chart_name
                escape_string("0".replace(".","").encode('utf-8')).strip(), #playlist
                escape_string("United States"), #chart_name_2
                escape_string("Apple Music Top 200"),
                datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
            )

        print ('Printing song #{} - {}').format(i, sql)
    except KeyError, e:
        print('KeyError detected --reason-- = {}'.format(e))
i = i+1
```

As always, any help that you guys can give is enormously appreciated!

Comment: If there are methods that you know won't work, you shouldn't be including them here - reduce your code to just the necessary parts for someone to understand your problem - a [MCVE].

Comment: Okay edits have been made. I removed the two places where the database values and methods were referenced. If the above code is run, it will return the top 50 songs with all the data I am looking for but not the remaining 150 I also need